# Mathematics not working when converting from LaTeX to docx (through markdown) using pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, docx, pandoc

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why I am unable to convert the simple *latex* file shown below **to** *docx* using `pandoc` (version 1.12.4.2, Compiled with texmath 0.6.6.3, highlighting-kate 0.5.11.1).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  1+1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `pandoc` commands I have used are:

```
pandoc --from=latex --to=markdown --output=FILE.md FILE.tex
pandoc --from=markdown+tex_math_dollars --to=docx --output=FILE.docx FILE.md
```

The result from the first command (the markdown file) is a file consisting of a single line: "`$$1+1$$`". The second command, which is supposed to produce the *docx* document, is empty.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using Markdown as an intermediary format instead of going straight from LaTeX to DOCX?

Comment: Hello Chris. The document I am converting will unfortunately need some manual changes. (The reason is extensive use of macros that pandoc seems to be unable to fully "unpack". Thus, the intermediate markdown step allows me to `sed` the troublemakers.) Moreover, I have tried to go straight from tex to docx in this simple example, but the output is still an empty file.

Comment: With the most recent version (1.14) this works as expected with the command. 

`pandoc -f latex -t markdown | pandoc -f markdown -o test.docx`

Comment: Thank you for your time testing the simple example. I believe "something" must have gone wrong when I installed `pandoc` the first time (using macports). I removed `pandoc` and all dependencies, reinstalled and now this simple example works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be one of those cases where the strategy "when in doubt re-install" does the trick. I lay the blame on OS-X Yosemite, it has been a "problematic child" since its inception.

Pandoc is dependent on an arsenal of haskell libraries and somewhere in the macports installation "something" must have gone wrong. I therefore uninstalled pandoc and all dependent packages as follows:

```
usr@cmptr $ sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents pandoc
```

Note `--follow-dependents` **not** `--follow-dependencies`, the latter is only for people who know what they are doing ([read more](https://guide.macports.org/#using.port.uninstall)).

**EDIT**

The pandoc version from mac Ports is often severely lagging compared the development. The reason for this is probably that the development is happening quite rapidly at the moment; therefore one can consider to install pandoc using the haskell "cabal" repository:

```
usr@cmptr $ sudo port install cabal
usr@cmptr $ cabal update
usr@cmptr $ cabal install pandoc
```

Also enable bibliography:

```
usr@cmptr $ cabal install pandoc-citeproc
```

And finally enable cross referencing (markdown notation, LaTeX -> Markdown conversion still iffy):

```
usr@cmptr $ cabal install pandoc-crossref
```

Add pandoc to `$PATH`:

```
usr@cmptr $ export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.cabal/bin/" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
```